# Message box C# on click refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio, messagebox

the message box is not coming up on my screen it stays in my task bar until I click on it. is there a way to prompt it to open without clicking on the box in the task bar.
also once I click OK is there a way I can refresh the page?

```
{
                string selection_price = DdPetPist.SelectedValue;
                var myquery = string.Format("UPDATE Animals SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE Specie ='{1}' and Country ='{0}'", ddlcountry.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim(), selection_price);
                da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName,LastName,Donation,Email,Adress,TellNo,DATE,Country,Specie) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Donation,@Email,@Adress,@TellNo,@DATE,@Country,@Specie)", cs);

                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname.Text);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname.Text);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation.Text);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specie", DdPetPist.SelectedValue);

                cs.Open();
                da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myquery, cs))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();

                MessageBox.Show
                ("Thank you for adopted a pet");

            }
```

Comment: it should not be doing what you are describing. sounds like maybe something else in the system is causing it to do this and not related to your application. Try doing a "this.Focus()" before you do a messagebox and see if that helps. perhaps its something else causing it to happen - more than likely.

Comment: If you haven't been able to find the problem or are just interested in having a "more proper" messagebox, you might want to consider the option of building your own one (a simple Form), what would give you full control on its structure, looks, etc. and on any iteration with other elements.

Comment: Hmm that may be a better idea. thank you